# Create a database lock with DBeaver

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, dbeaver

I am looking for a way to create a lock in my Oracle database with DBeaver that I need for testing my application.

A `SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID=123 FOR UPDATE` would do fine, but locks of course only for the duration of its exection. Can I prolong the locking period to some dozens of seconds by not committing until I want or pregiven time has expired?

Comment: Set autocommit option to false: https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Auto-and-Manual-Commit-Modes/ (or via JDBC parameter in the *Connection settings* -> *Initialization*)

Answer (score 1):

Use a PL/SQL block and sleep:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_row TBL%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSTIMESTAMP);

  SELECT *
  INTO   v_row
  FROM   TBL
  WHERE ID=123
  FOR UPDATE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSTIMESTAMP);
  DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP(12);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYSTIMESTAMP);

  -- COMMIT or ROLLBACK etc.
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WJ8borG5) (Note: unsurprisingly, the fiddle has a 12 second delay when you run it).

Answer (score 1):

For testing locking, I would just make a new session (sqlplus or your favorite DB client software) and do an update without committing.

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET id = id
 WHERE id = 123;

-- do nothing else until you are done testing, then manually:

ROLLBACK;
```

While this session is holding a row lock, you use your app to establish its own connection and feature the behavior you are looking for.

You can also lock the entire table if you prefer:

```
LOCK TABLE tbl;
```

Then commit or rollback to release.

Comment: Works fine in sqlplus, but my question was specifically about DBeaver.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what client you use. As long as your client program options don't have a "autocommit" feature enabled, Oracle is Oracle and should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to manual commit via the toolbar of DBeaver turned out to be the most convenient solution for my problem.

[image]